# spring-boot-starter-webflux can't use AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver

Tags: internationalization, spring-webflux

spring-boot-starter-webflux can not use org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver

so how can spring-boot-starter-webflux use resolveLocale?In other words, what is there in reactor that is similar to resolveLocale?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring WebFlux is configuring and using by default a `org.springframework.web.server.i18n. LocaleContextResolver` (with `org.springframework.web.server.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver` and `org.springframework.web.server.i18n.FixedLocaleContextResolver` as implementations).

You can inject the `java.util.Locale` as a Controller argument (if you're using the annotation variant of Spring WebFlux), or inject and use the configured `LocaleContextResolver` bean and use it directly.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply,when use Controller argument can get the Locale,thank you.