# How to configure WebFlux for i18n

Tags: java, spring-boot, internationalization, spring-webflux

How to implement localization support in WebFlux.
I tried to configure Localization using

```
 @Bean
 public MessageSource messageSource() {
 var messageSource = new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
 messageSource.setBasenames("i18n/messages");
 messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
 return messageSource;
}

@Bean(name = "localeResolver")
public LocaleContextResolver localeResolver() {
return new AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver();
}
```

I'm sending a request with localization key like 'en-US'. I put 'Accept-Language' in the header. I set my locale into that header.
But it did not work. Spring got default locale.
How is it fixed?

Comment: Checkout: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51780423/spring-boot-starter-webflux-cant-use-acceptheaderlocaleresolver

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with

```
    @Primary
    @Bean
    public LocaleContextResolver localeResolver() {
        AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver localeResolver = new AcceptHeaderLocaleContextResolver();
        localeResolver.setDefaultLocale(Locale.US);
    }
```

@Primary is matter